# plone4.3 add-on document viewer error

Tags: plone

i'm setting a Plone server. and set add-on Document Viewer on it.
but when i convert .doc on broswer i get error.

Exception in thread "main" org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.OfficeException: failed to start and connect
    at org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.ManagedOfficeProcess.startAndWait(ManagedOfficeProcess.java:64)
    at org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.PooledOfficeManager.start(PooledOfficeManager.java:101)
    at org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.ProcessPoolOfficeManager.start(ProcessPoolOfficeManager.java:62)
    at org.artofsolving.jodconverter.cli.Convert.main(Convert.java:112)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.OfficeException: could not establish connection
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
    at org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.ManagedOfficeProcess.startAndWait(ManagedOfficeProcess.java:62)
    ... 3 more

from debug information i know the error come from a command:

```
java -Djava.awt.headless=true
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/docsplit-0.7.2/vendor/logging.properties
-cp /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/docsplit-0.7.2/build:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/docsplit-0.7.2/vendor/'*'
-jar /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/docsplit-0.7.2/vendor/jodconverter/jodconverter-core-3.0-beta-4.jar
-r /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/docsplit-0.7.2/vendor/conf/document-formats.js /tmp/tmpPYP2u5/dump.doc /tmp/tmpPYP2u5/dump.pdf  2>&1
```

but if i run it in bash with root privileges. i get no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change libreoffice to openoffice3.org then the problem disapeared